# Closing or hiding an info box with an x

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

I have tried searching for clues, but drawn a big blank. Probably I am searching for the wrong thing!

I have created a basic info block on a page.

I would like to give users the option to hide or close that box by clicking on an x.

I am assuming that I would need to use a cookie - but no idea where to start! Maybe jquery, as I have that loaded on every page for other elements?

The one important factor is that it should re-appear when new information is displayed.

How is that done? Can anyone assist?

Thanks!

Comment: could you please post your code and if possible jsfiddle link too.

Comment: You should also consider reading things like this http://htmldog.com/guides/javascript/beginner/

Comment: Hi, per your understanding, this is what you are looking for:
[BootStrap Alert JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y3d3D/63/)

Comment: Rajesh - thanks. No the reverse I guess - this is on many sites, say a welcome to x site and an x on the right to hide that info block.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've read the beginners javascript guide Nicolas linked for you and maybe a jQuery tut, you're probably going to end up writing something like this.

Javascript

```
jQuery('div.xbutton').click(function(){
jQuery('div.infoblock').hide();
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="infoblock">Information text <div class="xbutton">X</div></div>
```

But that's in the future, so start with reading the guide. It'll be plenty helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
<div id="content" style="display:none;">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    Some text
</div>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        if (!readCookie('messageClosed')){
            jQuery('#content').show();
        }
        jQuery('#content .close').click(function(){
            jQuery('#content').slideUp();
            createCookie('messageClosed', 1, 365);
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

For functions readCookie and createCookie look this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1460174/2828391